# Techniques of showing the Order

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory

In their paper [The integral of Riemann Xi Function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4348), Lagarias and Montague show that the integral

$$\Xi_{\lambda}^{-1}(z)=2\int_0^{\infty}e^{\lambda u^2}\phi(u)\Big(  \frac{\sin zu}{u}\Big)\;du$$
is entire. Now, using the techniques of [Polya](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/crll.1927.158.6/html?lang=en), they mention that it is of order $1$ (Lemma 3.2 [Riemann Xi](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.4348)). Can someone explain what technique they mention here and how they applied it to determine that it is of order $1$? Any help would be appreciated.

I tried to understand the technique that was used, but the paper is mostly in German, and I'm not familiar with the jargon used. I also don't have access to an English translation.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since $\phi\lesssim \exp (-e^u)$ (from the paper) and $|\sin uz/u|\lesssim e^{u|z|}$, this boils down to showing that something like $\sum 2^{-n} e^{|z| \log n}$ can be estimated by $\exp( |z|^{1+\epsilon})$, which is easy by splitting the sum into two parts, at $N=|z|^{1+\epsilon}$.